# How do base linux distributions differ from the same distro on a VPS

Tags: centos, lxc, docker

I have centos 6.5 vps hosted by a 3rd party. I had planned to install docker on the vps but started to recieve lxc-start errors. This was wierd as I installed the docker without issue on a Vagrant box with a base centos 6.5 base image. I ran uname -a on both machines. My question is can software installations be trusted using virtualization solutions like VirtualBox?

VPS - `2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64`

Vagrant Box - `2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64`

After attempting to run a private registry on the vps I get the following lxc message.

docker logs 5baf37aa62a3

`lxc-start: Device or resource busy - failed to set memory.use_hierarchy to 1; continuing
lxc-start: Device or resource busy - failed to set memory.use_hierarchy to 1; continuing
2014-10-14 22:17:17,875 WARNING: Cache storage disabled!
2014-10-14 22:17:17,876 WARNING: LRU cache disabled!
2014-10-14 22:17:18,089 WARNING: No S3 region specified, using boto default region, this may affect performance and stability.`

This eventually lead me to https://github.com/lxc/lxc/issues/236 which seems to mean that my kernel is not up to date enough. Its just odd that I was able to run the same container/image locally through Vagrant/Virtual Box on Mac OSX Host.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Stop and think about what a [VPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) is. It's a form of virtualized or resource-separated server running on the vendor's hardware. There's a good chance that its already using a containerized solution (*OpenVZ, LXC, Parallels*), thus making it unlikely that you'd be able to run your own nested LXC instance.

The key here is to check with the provider to see if they have Docker-friendly or LXC-friendly VPS instances available. Some do, some don't...